# How to add two UNIX timestamps together, then calculate percentage of each timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix-timestamp

I have two UNIX timestamps that I want to add together to create a 'total' time with, but then I also would like to calculate how much of the total each timestamp is worth in percentage. For example:

```
var x = 123456;
var y = 1234;
var total = 124690;

x is % of total, y is % of total.
```

How can I achieve this in javascript? Do I need to convert the UNIX timestamp to a standard format, before calculating the percentages somehow?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to "add" dates. I suspect you're misusing the "Unix timestamp" term. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: @pXL—No need for brackets, the order doesn't matter (though precedence means evaluation proceeds from left to right): `x / total * 100`.

Comment: @Álvaro Sure, I have the 2 UNIX timestamps that when added together theoretically produce a length of time, or a time range. Each timestamp represents a value, so I want to calculate something like 80% of the total time, the color was red and 20% of the time the color was green. Hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: So you have, e.g., `20th August 2010` and `31st December 2013` and you want to add them together to produce... what exactly? *(Please note you can edit questions to add clarifications or further info.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said "*I want to add together to create a 'total' time*", I assume you mean just "time lengths", probably in seconds, i.e., you want to know how much percentage goes to each of the two events. These are **not** [Unix timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) (which are integer representations of dates, i.e., time lengths since the start of the Unix epoch).

Do this:

```
var x = 123456;
var y = 1234;
var total = x + y;

alert("x is " + Math.round(x / total * 100) + "% of total, y is " + Math.round(y / total * 100) + "% of total");
```

If you want more digits in percentages, for example two, use

```
alert("x is " + (Math.round(x / total * 10000) / 100) + "% of total, y is " + (Math.round(y / total * 10000) / 100) + "% of total");
```